# XML Message (JAXB) sent via JMS is null

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, jms, advanced-queuing

I want to send XML generated from an object using Springs `Jaxb2marshaller` and `jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(object)` to oracle queue (AQ). For some reason when I send the message, null is inserted into oracle queue. When I remove a few fields from that object class or those fields are null - message is delivered normally. With those fields back - again null. When debugging, I see that correct xml message is formed but have no idea why there is null in the database. No exceptions are thrown (or at least I can't find them). Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to do two things. First, accept that a bug in your code is more likely than one in either Spring or your messaging system.

Comment: Second, narrow down your scope of debugging. You say that "correct XML message is formed." Where do you see that? If it's on the receiving side, then you don't have to concern yourself with anything on the sending side. Then you say"why there is null in the database." Is this your only indication of a problem? If yes, it means that the problem is where you extract fields from the message and write them to the database. That is where you should spend your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with JAXB or Spring, it was oracle queue's type. Its type was `SYS.AQ$_JMS_MESSAGE` which can receive messages only of type `VARCHAR2`, which maximum equivalent in java is 500 symbols `String`. When `String` size exceeded 500 symbols, null was enqueued.

The solution was to change AQ's type to `SYS.XMLTYPE` (this type of queue can receive XML's up to 4GB). Of course, message sending method had to be modified. Before sending, `String` which was XML had to be converted to `XMLType`.